# <> ' ' condition in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have never encountered this before:

```
fieldname <> ''
```

How would this condition be read in Oracle PL/SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'll always be false since Oracle doesn't support zero-length strings. It treats them as null instead, and null isn't equal or unequal to anything, even itself.

Comment: The condition will evaluate to UNKNOWN, which will *usually* be treated as false, but not always.  It depends on the context, which is a little confusing here.

Comment: That's right. Oracle does treat '' AS `null`. Moreover, the result of evaluation `x = null` is `null`. You cannot negate the result back to be true, as the negation of `null` is `null` itself. That is why SQL has the `... IS NULL` keyword to check whether a value is null. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 1):

fieldname not equal to blank string

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Operators

Comment: Zero length strings are null in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

fieldname not equal to empty string

Answer (score 0):

This corresponds to Not equal(<>) to null ('')